# Google C2DM server side performance

Tags: performance, android-c2dm

My application sends notifications to the customers in bulks. For example at 8am every day a back-end systems generates notifications for 50K customers, and those notifications should be delivered in a reasonable time.
During performance testing I've discovered that sending a single push request to C2DM server takes about 400 millis which is far too long. I was told that a production quota may provide better performance, but will it reduce to 10 millis?
Besides, I need C2DM performance marks before going to production because it may affect the implementation - sending the requests from multiple threads, using asynchronous http client etc.
Does anyone knows about the C2DM server benchmarks or any performance-related server implementation guidelines?

Thanks,
Artem

Answer (score 0):

I use appengine, which makes the delivery of a newsletter to 1 million users a very painful task. Mostly because the c2dm API doesn't support multiple users delivery, which makes it necessary to create one http request per user.

The time to the c2dm server to respond will depend on your latency from the google servers. In my case (appengine) it's very small.

My advice to you is to create as many threads as possible, since the threads will be waiting for the IO over the network. If you every pass the quota, you can always ask permission for more traffic.